# Differences in the definition of sub-basis

Tags: general-topology

Munkres defines a subbasis as follows: "A subbasis $S$ for a topology on $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ whose
union equals $X$. The topology generated by the subbasis $S$ is defined to be the collec-
tion $\tau$ of all unions of finite intersections of elements of $S$"

1.) If I understand it correctly, only the first sentence is the definition of subbasis. But that seems quite useless without the second sentence. I.e., shouldnt the second sentence actually be part of the definition of subbasis as well, i.e., as I read it the second sentence defines what a topology generated by a subbasis is and not what a subbasis is.

2.) Wikipedia states that this definition differs from the usual definition where a subbasis is a subset of the powerset of $X$ such that the system of all finite intersections of elements from the subbasis forms a basis.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase
But where is there a difference here? Wikipedia says that the difference is that the definition of Munkres explicitely demands that the subbasis covers $X$ but the usual definition of subbasis does that implicitely as well due to the empty intersections being equal to $X$, no?

3.) In some lecture notes, I have encountered the definition of subbasis that is the standard one, except that it requires that the subbasis be non-empty. Does that change anything about the definition? Can we still do empty intersections of a subcollection of the subbasis? How does the definitions that do not explicitely require the subbasis to be empty handle that pathological case?

Comment: Yeah, there are two ways of defining a sub-basis. You can use a sub-basis to define a topology, or you can take an existing topology and assert some collection of open sets is a sub-basis for that topology.

Comment: The key is that any collection of sets is a sub-space for a topology of their union. That is different from a basis for a topology - you need a lot of conditions on a collection of sets to make it a basis for the topology.

Comment: Yes, meant sub-basis, not subspace. @AnneBauval

Comment: ok thank you and where are now the differences and why do ppl choose different definitions?

Comment: There aren't really any differences - they are equivalent. Usually, you don't encounter sub-basis before you encounter a basis, and Munkres' definition is the odd one, I think. I don't know why anybody would choose one over the other, other than the emphasis that any set of sets determines a topology, rather than emphasizing finding a sub-basis for a given topology.

Comment: Munkres' definition defines *a* sub-basis to be any set of subsets of $X$ that covers $X$. Each one of these generates *some* topology on $X$ (via finite intersections and arbitrary unions of elements). The topology generated by a particular sub-basis is the coarsest topology on $X$ in which each element of the sub-basis is open.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews but the wikipedia page says that the definition from munkres and the usual definition are not equivalent

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to think about it is this.

Any collection $\mathcal F$ of subsets of a set $X$ generates a topology on $X$, in the sense that there is a smallest topology $\tau$ on $X$ that contains $\mathcal F$. The topology $\tau$ is the intersection of all the topologies on $X$ containing $\mathcal F$.  That all makes sense even if $\mathcal F$ is empty, or if $\mathcal F$ does not cover $X$.  For example, if $\mathcal F$ is empty, the smallest topology containing the empty collection of subsets of $X$ is the smallest possible topology, namely $\tau=\{\emptyset,X\}$.

In that situation, we can say $\mathcal F$ is a *subbasis* (or *subbase*) for the topology $\tau$ to mean that it generates $\tau$ in the sense above.  And note that any collection of subsets of $X$ whatsoever is always a subbasis for *some* topology, namely the topology that it generates.

And on the other hand, if you are given a topology $\tau$ to start with, one can find collections of subsets of $X$ that will generate $\tau$ in the sense above, and any such collection is called a subbasis for $\tau$.  (For example, one can choose $\mathcal F$ equal to $\tau$ itself: any topology is a subbasis for itself.  In general there are many subbases.)  In any case, subbasis just means "generates the topology".

Some authors (like Munkres) like to add the covering condition and the non-empty condition.  It does not really change anything fundamental.  If the collection is not a cover, you can always add $X$ itself if you want and that will give you a cover.  But I find it easier just to reason in terms of smallest topology generated by a collection of sets, without bothering about a cover.

Note that the description of a topology from a subbasis given above is top down in a way.  It can also be described bottom up (exercise).  The topology generated by some collection $\mathcal F$ of sets will be the set of arbitrary unions of finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal F$.  When using that approach, it may make things easier if you start with a cover of $X$.  But even in this case, it's not absolutely necessary if you use the "nullary conventions" for intersection and union of subsets of $X$ (namely, an empty intersection is the whole set and an empty union is the empty set).

---

Here is an illustrative example.  Suppose $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and $\mathcal F=\{\{a,b\}, \{a,c\}\}$.  Note that $\mathcal F$ is not a cover of $X$.  Now what is the topology on $X$ generated by $\mathcal F$?

Using the top down approach: what is the smallest topology $\tau$ that contains $\mathcal F$?  Well, the topology has to contain the intersection $\{a,b\}\cap\{a,c\}=\{a\}$ (intersection of two open sets is open).  And it has to contain the union $\{a,b\}\cup\{a,c\}=\{a,b,c\}$ (union of open sets is open).  And any topology always contains $\emptyset$ and $X$ itself.  So it has to contain at least the family of sets $\{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,c\}, \{a,b,c\}, \{a,b,c,d\}\}$.  And you can check that that family satisfies the definition of a topology, so it's *the* topology on $X$ generated by $\mathcal F$.

Using the bottom up approach.  We first get all the finite intersections of members of $\mathcal F$, meaning taking every intersection of a finite subfamily of $\mathcal F$.  That gives us $\mathcal F$ itself, plus $\{a,b\}\cap\{a,c\}=\{a\}$. (clue: something missing here...)  Then we take arbitrary unions of these things and we get: $\{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,c\}, \{a,b,c\}\}$.

Now you are going to ask: we don't get $X$, right?  That's because I purposely omitted something.  In the intersections of finite subfamilies of $\mathcal F$, we also have to consider the empty subfamily ($\mathcal G = \emptyset\subseteq\mathcal F$).  And its intersection is what gives all of $X$.  That's what is meant by the "nullary convention".  It's actually not a random convention, but a consequence of the definition of the union of a family of sets.  In more general situations the union of a empty family is not well-defined (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)#Nullary_intersection).  But in the context of subsets of a given set $X$, it's perfectly well-defined: the result is $X$ (easy to figure out if you think about it).

Beginning students may not have encountered the concept of an empty family and may have difficulty with the use of abstraction.  Munkres was writing specifically for an undergraduate audience, that's probably why he added the requirement to start with a cover of $X$ (then you get $X$ as a union).  In that case, for the finite intersection one only has to look at intersection of finite *nonempty* subfamilies of $\mathcal F$.  In more advanced text, things get simpler by assuming students know about empty intersections and empty unions.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. So regarding the bottom up approach: You say it is not necessary to start with a cover of X, because you can use the nullary convention. But using the nullary convention is equivalent to demand that your collection covers X, no? Because you can always form the empty intersection which will always give you X, right? So does that mean that we need to either demand that our collection covers X or we neeed to use the nullary convention, which in the end would mean that we always need to include X in this approach one way or another?

Comment: Not exactly.  Top down and bottom up approaches are two ways of describing the same thing.  They are meant to be define exactly the same thing.  I'll add a detailed example in the answer itself.

Comment: Ok thank you and another point of confusion I have is if F is the empty set and we view F as a basis and want to generate a topology from it, in a constructive way, i.e., by forming unions of the elements of F. Then I can never get to form anything else than the empty set, so how do I every get X (and I need X because otherwise it is not a topology)?
And maybe more generally: F does not cover X, i.e., if we cannot create X by a union of elements from F, then we can never create a topology like that, because we need X for a topology?

Comment: I have added the example, hope that clarifies things.  BTW in your last comment: the empty set cannot be a basis in general.  You meant "subbasis", I suppose.  Anyway, see if the example helps.

Comment: Rereading your comment, you are correct that a "basis" for a topology always needs to be a cover.  But we are taking about "subbasis" here, which is a less restrictive notion (and slightly less useful too).

Comment: Hi thanks for your expanded answer and the example. Some of the additional explanations were indeed very helpful. I am just wondering: You are talking about the empty unions being the whole set X but I think what you mean are the empty intersections that give the whole X. Empty union gives empty set right? another question: In the bottom up approach where do we actually get the empty set from after having taken arbitrary unions?

Comment: And yet another question: Do top down and bottom up approach differ in the uniqueness of their results? I.e., does one generate a unique result (topology) and the other doesnt? As far as I know the base (or subbase) for a topology is not unique generally. Also when I start with a topology and apply some top down procedure to determine the base, and then I generate the topology of that base with a bottom up procedure, do I end up with the same topology I started with?

Comment: Sorry and yet two more questions that came to my mind: If I have some collection F and generate the smallest topology that contains F by intersecting all topologies that contain F, can I make any statement about whether F is a basis or a subbasis? (I mean it will always be a subbasis if I understand correctly but it may also even be a basis, but can we know that without checking more properties?) 
The other question is: I have seen the usual definition of a subbasis but in addition it requires the subbasis to be nonempty (it doesnt require it to cover X though). What does that change/imply?

Comment: Sorry, I just write down questions as they come: In your minimal example where F=emptyset. I am wondering what the basis B is that we get from F by finite intersections. I will just be B={X} right? But that is a little bit weird becaues I thought that F should be a subset of B, or was that a wrong assumption by me?

Comment: For your questions about uniqueness, there is no uniqueness of a basis or subbasis.  A topology can have many bases and many subbases (as you can see already with the example of the real numbers).  And also every base is a subbase.

Comment: For your last comment when $\mathcal F=\emptyset$, it is correct that the corresponding basis will be $\mathcal B=\{X\}$.  And indeed $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathcal B$ in that case.

Comment: I suggest you spend some time studying https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology) before asking any more questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Regarding how you get X you wrote "In the intersections of finite subfamilies of F
, we also have to consider the empty subfamily (G=∅⊆F
). And its union is what gives all of X
. That's what is meant by the "nullary convention". It's actually not a random convention, but a consequence of the definition of the union of a family of sets. In more general situations the union of a empty family is not well-defined". So it seems like you are talking about the union of empty set being X but that is the intersection

Comment: Yes thanks i have read those articles already. To me it just isnt clear why every base is a subbase. Because that requires that a Basis contains finite intersections i suppose. And i am not sure why that should hold

Comment: @guest1 thanks for pointing out the typo.  Now fixed.

Comment: @guest1 You have not read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology) carefully enough.  I suggest you reread it until you fully understand the details.  And please try to understand by yourself first, instead of relying on people to predigest everything for you.   Let's stop this never ending discussion here.  If something is not clear, you can ask a separate question.